# Suma 2 puntos en vez de 1, quiz sencillo en javascript

Tags: javascript

soy nuevo en Javascript y estoy aprendiendo con proyectos secundarios en mi tiempo libre. Hace ya 2 semanas que estoy intentando hacer un quiz de preguntas y me esta costando muchisimo, sobretodo por el error este del puntaje que no se como solucionar.

La idea es que el contador de puntos sume cuando acertas, pero ademas esta el contador de preguntas que siempre tiene que sumar 1, independientemente de lo que respondas. Pero **despues de la 1ra pregunta, todas las siguientes suman 2 en vez de 1** a cada contador. Aca adjunto un video breve del error: https://gyazo.com/9fbdf63508b2713992935d813f29788e

Este es el codigo del .JS

```
let pregunta = document.getElementById('preguntafinal');

let puntaje = document.getElementById('puntaje');

let opcion1 = document.getElementById('opcion1');
let opcion2 = document.getElementById('opcion2');
let opcion3 = document.getElementById('opcion3');
let opcion4 = document.getElementById('opcion4');

let puntito1 = document.querySelector('puntito1');


let idPreg = 0;
let respSeleccionada;
let puntosTotales = 0;
let preguntasTotales = 0;

function iterarJuego() {


    pregunta.innerText = arrayPreguntas[idPreg].preg;

    opcion1.innerText = arrayPreguntas[idPreg].opcionuno;
    opcion2.innerText = arrayPreguntas[idPreg].opciondos;
    opcion3.innerText = arrayPreguntas[idPreg].opciontres;
    opcion4.innerText = arrayPreguntas[idPreg].opcioncuatro;;

    elegirRespuesta();


}


function elegirRespuesta(){

    opcion1.addEventListener("click", asd=> {

        respSeleccionada = arrayPreguntas[idPreg].opcionuno;
        funAnalizar(respSeleccionada);

    });

    opcion2.addEventListener("click", asd=> {

        respSeleccionada = arrayPreguntas[idPreg].opciondos;
        funAnalizar(respSeleccionada);

    });

    opcion3.addEventListener("click", asd=> {

        respSeleccionada = arrayPreguntas[idPreg].opciontres;
        funAnalizar(respSeleccionada);
    });

    opcion4.addEventListener("click", asd=> {

        respSeleccionada = arrayPreguntas[idPreg].opcioncuatro;
        funAnalizar(respSeleccionada);

    });

}



function funAnalizar(){

    console.log(respSeleccionada);
    console.log(arrayPreguntas[idPreg].error);

    if (respSeleccionada == arrayPreguntas[idPreg].error) {

        console.log("correcto");
        respCorrecta(respSeleccionada);

    }

    else if (respSeleccionada != arrayPreguntas[idPreg].error) {

        console.log("incorrecto");
        respIncorrecta(respSeleccionada);
    }

}


function respCorrecta(){

        puntosTotales++;
        preguntasTotales++;
        puntaje.innerText = puntosTotales + "/" + preguntasTotales;
        idPreg++;
        iterarJuego(idPreg);
        console.log("ja");
}


function respIncorrecta(){

        preguntasTotales++;
        puntaje.innerText = puntosTotales + "/" + preguntasTotales;
        idPreg++;
        iterarJuego (idPreg); 
        console.log("jant");
}

arrayPreguntas = [ {

        idPreg : 0,
        preg : "Que significa AI en Japonés?",

             opcionuno: 'amor',  
             opciondos: 'carcel', 
             opciontres: 'pizza',   
             opcioncuatro: 'caja', 
             error:'amor'       
            


        } , {

        idPreg: 1,
        preg: "Cual es el hiragana 'ME' ?",

             opcionuno: 'ぬ',  
             opciondos: 'ね', 
             opciontres: 'ぐ',   
             opcioncuatro: 'め',     
             error:'め'  

        } , { 

        idPreg: 2,
        preg: "En hiragana: DESAYUNO , ALMUERZO , CENA ?",

             opcionuno: 'ぬ',  
             opciondos: 'ね', 
             opciontres: 'ぐ',   
             opcioncuatro: 'め',     
             error:'め'

        } , {

        idPreg: 3,
        preg: "Como se dice madre y padre ?",

             opcionuno: 'chichi hana',  
             opciondos: 'hana mitsu', 
             opciontres: 'kirei chichi',   
             opcioncuatro: 'undo chichi',   
             error:'kirei chichi'
        } , {

        idPreg: 4,
        preg: "Que significa きれい ?",

             opcionuno: 'rey y reina',  
             opciondos: 'lindo y linda', 
             opciontres: 'hermoso y hermosa',   
             opcioncuatro: 'salvaje y saldro',  
             error:'lindo y linda'
        }
]




iterarJuego();
```

Comment: Creo que es porque tu función iterarJuego está añadiendo un nuevo listener a cada elemento (opción). Entonces, tendrás siempre un nuevo listener cuando avanzas en tu juego y por tanto repetirás la suma. Deberías quitar primero los listener de cada elemento mediante `removeEventListener` y luego volver a crearlos con `addEventListener`.

Answer (score 0):

He preparado un ejemplo usando tu array de preguntas.

```js
arrayPreguntas = [{

  idPreg: 0,
  preg: "Que significa AI en Japonés?",

  res0: 'amor',
  res1: 'carcel',
  res2: 'pizza',
  res3: 'caja',
  valida: 0



}, {

  idPreg: 1,
  preg: "Cual es el hiragana 'ME' ?",

  res0: 'ぬ',
  res1: 'ね',
  res2: 'ぐ',
  res3: 'め',
  valida: 3

}, {

  idPreg: 2,
  preg: "En hiragana: DESAYUNO , ALMUERZO , CENA ?",

  res0: 'ぬ',
  res1: 'ね',
  res2: 'ぐ',
  res3: 'め',
  valida: 3

}, {

  idPreg: 3,
  preg: "Como se dice madre y padre ?",

  res0: 'chichi hana',
  res1: 'hana mitsu',
  res2: 'kirei chichi',
  res3: 'undo chichi',
  valida: 2
}, {

  idPreg: 4,
  preg: "Que significa きれい ?",

  res0: 'rey y reina',
  res1: 'lindo y linda',
  res2: 'hermoso y hermosa',
  res3: 'salvaje y saldro',
  valida: 1
}];

let puntuacion = 0;
let contadorPreguntas = 0;
let preguntaActual = null;

function siguientePregunta() {
  if (arrayPreguntas.length > 0) {
    preguntaActual = arrayPreguntas.shift();
  } else {
    preguntaActual = null;
  }
}

function redibujarPregunta() {
  document.getElementById('pregunta').innerHTML = preguntaActual.preg;
  let respuestas = document.getElementsByClassName('respuesta');
  for (let i = 0; i < respuestas.length; i++) {
    // actualizar "value" del input
    respuestas[i].children[0].value = preguntaActual["res" + i];
    respuestas[i].children[0].checked = false;
    // actualizar texto de "label"
    respuestas[i].children[1].innerText = preguntaActual["res" + i];
  }
}

function avanzarQuiz() {
  siguientePregunta();
  if (preguntaActual !== null) {
    redibujarPregunta();
  } else {
    alert('Has terminado. Tu puntuación final es: ' + puntuacion);
  }
}

function validar(i) {
  if (preguntaActual != null) {
    let p = preguntaActual;
    return p["res" + i] === p["res" + p.valida];
  }
  return false;
}

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  const inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('respuesta');

  for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      if (e.target && e.target.tagName !== 'INPUT') {
        this.children[0].click();
      }
    });
    inputs[i].children[0].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      if (validar(i)) {
        puntuacion++;
      }
      avanzarQuiz();
    });
  }
  avanzarQuiz();
});
```

```html
<p id="pregunta">
  <p>
    <div class="respuesta">
      <input type="radio" name="res" id="res0" value="" />
      <label for="res0"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="respuesta">
      <input type="radio" name="res" id="res1" value="" />
      <label for="res1"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="respuesta">
      <input type="radio" name="res" id="res2" value="">
      <label for="res2"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="respuesta">
      <input type="radio" name="res" id="res3" value="">
      <label for="res3"></label>
    </div>
```

He utilizado el evento "load" para preparar listeners para cada elemento `div.respuesta`. No necesito eliminar los listener tras cada pregunta.

He actualizado los nombres de las propiedades de los objetos de preguntas. Por ejemplo, la propiedad "res0" corresponde a la primera respuesta. De esta manera, puedo acceder a la propiedad mediante `pregunta["res"+valorNumerico]`.

Recomiendo visitar https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript para ampliar fácilmente tu habilidad en JS.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]